# Trying to call a global variable in another function and getting NameError:

Tags: python, csv, variables, global, nameerror

First time poster, new to Python, so be easy on me. Also apologize for any formatting faux pas as again, I'm new here.

I'm writing a Python script to parse through a .csv and transfer the necessary information into a .xml format, and I'm trying to make it so that the end-user can select the .csv they want to use rather than having to actually open the code and copy/paste a filepath into the function.

I've got a basic GUI going with the tkinter module and I've got a function that opens a filedialog and allows the user to select a file.

From what I understand in what I've written, this function returns a filepath as a TextIO wrapper object that I'm then converting to a string, trimming down, and trying to store in a global variable for use in the function that will actually run the "conversion"; however, I am running into a NameError in the next function that says my variable is not defined.

Output is:

```
line 45, in <module>
    with open(imported_csv, newline='') as csv:
NameError: name 'imported_csv' is not defined. Did you mean: 'import_csv'?
```

For now, I'm just trying to get the function to read the csv and output the data to the terminal so I can make sure that the function is actually reading the csv before I go any further.

I'm sure I'm just missing something really basic, but I may be going about this totally the wrong way. Please help! Code follows below:

`

```
import csv
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
# from tkinter import ttk #<---for styles

### ~GUI code~ ###
## static GUI elements
root = Tk()
root.title("CSV to XML converter for Command camera servers")
root.geometry('1200x600')
subtitle = Label(root, text = "Select a csv to import:")
subtitle.grid(column=0, row=0)

## interactive GUI elements
def converting_text():
    subtitle.configure(text = 'Converting, please wait...')
    convert_button.configure(fg = 'grey')

convert_button = Button(root, text = "Convert Now", command = lambda: [converting_text(), conversion()])
convert_button.grid(column=1, row=7)

### import csv
selected_csv = Label(text = '')
selected_csv.grid(column=2, row=1)

def import_csv():
    global imported_csv
    imported_csv = filedialog.askopenfilename() #opens dialog window to select a file
    imported_csv = open(imported_csv, 'r') #retrieves filepath from dialog
    imported_csv = str(imported_csv) #converts filepath to a string
    selected_csv.configure(text = imported_csv.lstrip("<_io.TextIOWrapper name=").rstrip(" mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>") + "'") #trims unnecessary chars from filepath
    return imported_csv

choose_file_button = Button(root, text = "Browse files", command = import_csv)
choose_file_button.grid(column=1, row=2)

## ~conversion function code~ ##
with open(imported_csv, newline='') as csv:
    def conversion():
        csvread = csv.reader(csv, delimiter=',')
        for row in csvread:
            print(', '.join(row))



root.mainloop()
```

`

Comment: You're getting a `NameError` because `imported_csv` is not yet defined in the global scope. `global imported_csv` is simply telling the interpreter, "The `imported_csv` I'm going to use in this function should be in global scope." When you initially reference `imported_csv` in global scope, the function defining it has not been run yet and as such, it has not been defined.

Comment: @Axe319 I have it declared as global in the import_csv function.. did I do this wrong?

Edit: Apologies, I didn't see your entire comment at first.

Okay. I understand what you're saying. How would you suggest reorganizing this? Should I write a super small function to run that pretty much just puts that variable in global scope?

Comment: You do have it declared as global within `import_csv`. The problem is, python has only run the top level code at the point you reach `with open(imported_csv, newline='') as csv:`. By top level code, I mean function signatures (`def` statements, not the body), and code not contained within a function. This is also why calling `conversion()` earlier in your code doesn't produce a `NameError` even though it's defined later in your code.

Comment: To start, just exchange the lines, `with open(imported_csv, newline='') as csv:` and `def conversion():`. At a more general level, it'll be helpful to you to get a better understanding of the [python execution model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html) as well the event loop style of programming that `tkinter` uses.

Comment: Okay. I did so and now I get this output: `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/julian.lutz/Documents/GitHub/Command-server-programming/7356-4087.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>"`

Looks like it isn't taking my string conversion and trimming as that is the entire object that is normally returned by that function.

Comment: `imported_csv = open(imported_csv, 'r')` this line is opening your file and handing back a file object. Then this line `with open(imported_csv, newline='') as csv:` is doing it again but attempting to open a string representation of the opened file object. Remove this line `imported_csv = open(imported_csv, 'r')` as it looks like you're attempting to convert it back afterwards anyway. It also means you can change to this `selected_csv.configure(text = imported_csv)` as well and remove this line `imported_csv = str(imported_csv)` since it's redundant.